# Simple WSO2 ESB Soap interface

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Myself: New to WSO2, Evaluating multiple ESB products

Here is what I am trying to do with wso2 ESB

1. Application "A" will send  a zipcode (SOAP-WDSL) to WSO2-ESB
2. WSo2 will use that zip-code and query National WeatherService and obtain
   the  Lati-Long for zipcode
   LatLonListZipCode method at 
      http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl
3. Return the lat-Lon  to Application "A"

Would someone please guide me , like where to start and the components needed so forth?

I am kind of confused by all the terminologies and over complicated product names and hierarchy (carbon, oxygen so forth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement what you simply need is to create a Proxy service in WSO2 ESB to invoke this Backend service.  (National WeatherService)

If you want to get started with WSO2 ESB I recommend you to 1st go though. [WSO2 ESB Sample guide](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples_index.html) and [WSO2 ESB Configuration](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples_index.html). Where you can get a head start using that.

For your scenario you can simply follow the below steps to create a simple WSDL Proxy create a working scenario which you can later improve (ex with routing , monitoring etc..)

1) Login to WSO2 ESB.

2) Go to Proxy Service Adding Section

3) Select WSDL Based Proxy as the Template

4) Give a Proxy name , WSDL url , Service name (ndfdXML) , WSDL Port (ndfdXMLPort) and tick Publish Same Service Contract

And create the service.

Now you have exposed the same service though WSO2 ESB. You can go to service list section.Get the Service EPR details and invoke the service using your application.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response.BTW I am getting the following error while testing it. <TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out</TryitProxyError>

Answer (score 1):

Below is a nice work done for beginners. Someting similar to your case 
http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/07/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2.html